# flutter run -d chrome --release throwing error Missing index.html (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

I just downloaded a project from GitHub

(https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app).
and when I run that using flutter run -d chrome --release it's showing an error

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cXnLmX-gXeOiI56Cv4oeVcyVFdDlqd02/view?usp=sharing

(I've tried this ["$ flutter build web" is throwing the error "Missing index.html"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316589/flutter-build-web-is-throwing-the-error-missing-index-html) but DIDN'T WORK )

I can run other projects in chrome

the output of flutter doctor

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cXnLmX-gXeOiI56Cv4oeVcyVFdDlqd02/view?usp=sharing

In short, I just want to run this project on chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316589/flutter-build-web-is-throwing-the-error-missing-index-html

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach and it works:

1. create a new flutter project
2. and now paste files of the old project into the new project.

in this way, the new project is already configured for the web and you can run it.

Comment: should I just paste my codes which are in the lib folder or have to paste all files

Answer (score 0):

cd back to the parent directory that the project is in.

run flutter create folder-name

This will repair the current project and add any missing files. You might need to open your pubspec.yaml file and pud get and pub upgrade to get everything working again.