# `flutter build web` is not creating a new build?

Tags: flutter

Going to my GitHub Pages, https://Andrious.GITHUB.IO/, you'll find the old Counter app.

However, following the document, [Build and release a web app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#deploying-to-the-web), I'm trying to override that with my latest efforts, but `flutter build web` doesn't 'overwrite' the counter app??

What am I missing?!

Even in my Android Studio!  If I run `flutter run -d Chrome`, it gives me the latest website:
[image]

However, after I do a build, `flutter run -d Chrome --release`, takes me back to the counter app??:
[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong....

*** UPDATE ***

ok, I deleted the folder, web, in my project folder (with pubspec.yaml) and then issued a flutter create . in that folder.

Of course, it recreates that web folder, but surely I shouldn't have to do that every time I want to build a release??

...with that, I think I can deploy a new website and replace that counter app at https://Andrious.GITHUB.IO/

I'm not going to delete that web folder every time, am I?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try opening on different browser or mode, there I did not find counter app on that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, when I searched a little longer, I found this answer ["$ flutter build web" is throwing the error "Missing index.html"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316589/flutter-build-web-is-throwing-the-error-missing-index-html)

This might happen when the project does not support the web, running the following command in the root directory of your project, will rebuild the app to support the web.

```
flutter create .
```

Then run the command in the same directory.

```
flutter build web
```